# React Native Android Native UI Component the @ReactProps doesn't execute

Tags: react-native

I have build a map Native UI Component at the Android platform. When the view is imported in the view as this

```
<AMapView style={styles.mapContainer} mode={2} onRegionChange={this._onReginChange.bind(this)}/>
```

The onRegionChange event is executed but the property method doesn't execute. [enter link description here](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.19/docs/native-components-android.html#content)

```
class AMapCustomView extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this._onRegionChange = this._onRegionChange.bind(this)
    }

    _onRegionChange(event: Event) {
        if (!this.props.onRegionChange) {
            return
        }
        this.props.onRegionChange(event.nativeEvent)
    }

    render() {
        return <RCTAMap {...this.props} onRegionChange={this._onRegionChange}/>
    }
}

AMapCustomView.propTypes = {
    ...View.propTypes,
    mode: PropTypes.number,
    onRegionChange: PropTypes.func
}

var RCTAMap = requireNativeComponent('RCTAMap', AMapCustomView)

module.exports = AMapCustomView;
```

Java Code:

```
@Override
public Map getExportedCustomDirectEventTypeConstants() {
    return MapBuilder.of(
            AMapLocationEvent.EVENT_NAME, MapBuilder.of("registrationName", "onRegionChange")
    );
}


@ReactProp(name="mode", defaultInt = 1)
public void setMode(AMapView mapView, int type) {
    Log.d(TAG, "mode:" + type);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you `import com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactProp;`, I think the path used to change and the old ReactProp will no more work in more recent React Native version.

Comment: Thanks you. Yeah, this was super-confusing for me too -- I don't know why, but the Android Studio IDE autcomplete suggested "import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactProp;" before "import com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactProp;". Why is it even suggesting the non-annotations version, as that path doesn't seem to exist?